# What do i need to pass in Ajax to upload a file via SFTP (JS + PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file, codeigniter-3

I want the user to insert in my page a PDF or image file.
Then i want to upload that file via SFTP with PHPSECLIB.
I want to pass the file via ajax with some more data.

```
        var file = this.files[0];
        alert('You have chosen the file ' + file.name);
        var data = new FormData();                
        data.append('file', file);
        var url_string = window.location.href;
        var url = new URL(url_string);
        var id = url.searchParams.get("id");
        var url="Invoice/uploadInvoice"                
        console.log(data);  
        console.log(file);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/SPI/Invoice/uploadInvoice", // point to server-side PHP script 
            dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: {file : data , id:id},                           
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(php_script_response){
                alert(php_script_response); // display response from the PHP script, if any
            }
        });
});
```

I expect someting in POST in function uploadInvoice and its output is NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i have done here is getting the file by elementID and getting the first and only file at position 0 from the input.

```
        var url_string = window.location.href;
        var url = new URL(url_string);
        var id = url.searchParams.get("id");
        var url="Invoice/uploadInvoice"            
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append("id", id);
        form_data.append("nrinvoice" , document.getElementById('nrinvoice').value);
        form_data.append("file", document.getElementById('input-excel').files[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo base_url('/Invoice/uploadInvoice') ?>/",
            method:"POST",
            data: form_data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
          ....
```